# Dynamically create instance variables from a list of classes

Tags: ruby, meta-programming

I have a situation, where I want to add many classes as instance variables of another class, plus perform some action on each class. The purpose is to have an 'app' with many 'views', to represent `PageObjects`.For instance:

```
class App
  attr_reader :login_view, :list_view, :create_view

  def initialize
    action([LoginView,ListView,CreateView])
    @login_view = LoginView.new
    @list_view = ListView.new
    @create_view = Create_view.new
  end
end

# App.new.login_view => [LoginView]
```

I came up with a solution which works:

```
module ClassToVar
  def create_instances_for(views)
    Array(views).each { |clazz| create_instance_for(clazz) }
  end

  private

  def create_instance_for(clazz)
    class_name = to_camel_case(clazz)
    variable_name = '@' + class_name
    instance_variable_set(variable_name, clazz.new)
    self.class.class_eval { attr_reader class_name.to_sym }
  end

  # *This could be done useing ActiveSupport, but I preferred to add it here*
  def to_camel_case(class_name)
    demodulize(class_name).gsub(/::/, '/')
                          .gsub(/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/, '\1_\2')
                          .gsub(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/, '\1_\2').tr("-", "_").downcase
  end

  def demodulize(class_name)
    class_name.to_s.split('::').last
  end
end

# class App include ClassToVar
#   def initialize
#     create_instances_for([ListView, LoginView, CreateView])
# end
#
```

I think there has to be a different way to solve it: Either a simpler way, or a different design, so I don't need to take this approach.

Any advice?

Comment: Curious.. the 'to_camel_case' method name does not make sense since it is actually taking it away from being camelcase and more so doing what the 'tableize' method does. Also, why create a demodulize method instead of using the existing demodulize method within Inflector? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-demodulize

Comment: Ups, that's right, it should be `to_snake_case`. I won't edit it, so the original code is there. As I commented, I did not want to require active support.